# error when upload Build on app store in corona sdk

Tags: coronasdk

When I am trying to upload the build on app store using distribution certificate through application loader then I am getting this error

ERROR ITMS-9000 :"The bundle "**Bundle name**" at bundle path '**path of bundle**' is not signed using Apple Submission certificate. "at SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAssets(MZltmspSoftwareAssetPackage)

I had try multiple things like.
1. Created new provisional profile for a app
2. Created new application on store
3. Created new certificated as well
Nothing is happening some Builds from same certificate and provisional profile are already uploaded from my account but now I getting the same error which i mentioned above.

When I am trying to upload the build created from Xcode than its working fine.

Step reproduce

1. Create the build for ios using corona sdk(Version number 2014.2325) using distribution certificate.
2. Than click on upload button to upload the build on app store
3. Application loader will open enter your account credential, select your application than select payload.ipa to upload the build.

After some time you get this error as I mention above

Version number
2014.2325

Help me out from this.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: In my case Using Xcode 5.1.1 and iOS 7 I was able to successfully upload by removing the `armv6` architecture from the target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely have an invalid key in your Keychain Access.  Most people who encounter this have to clean out all of the development bits in Keychain Access and start the Key, Certificate, Provisioning profile from the beginning.  It helps to reboot the Mac after clearing out Keychain Access.

Some others find that invalid characters in the app name or the folder where your Corona SDK project is located.

Rob